# Leaderboard code error when it doesnt need to be updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code, I have used enumerate and idx to update my leaderboard in a text file. However, when the scores should not be updated, an error occurs in the shell. It shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Program\Program.py", line 140, in <module>
    if item.split(', ')[1] == winner[1] and int(item.split(', ')[0]) < int(winner[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code that I have used is:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(leaderboard):
    if item.split(', ')[1] == winner[1] and int(item.split(', ')[0]) < int(winner[0]):
            leaderboard[idx] = '{}, {}'.format(winner[0], winner[1])
    else:
        pass
```

Please can you help me sort this error, as I don't understand what the error is or how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index out of range occurs when you're accessing an index greater than the contents of the array.

You're splitting `item` here, so the split method does not return an array which contains 2 items but 0.

## Examples:

```
item = "first"
splitItems = item.split(', ')

splitItems[1] // Throws IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

```
item = "first, "
splitItems = item.split(', ')

splitItems[0] // Works, the contents are 'first'
splitItems[1] // Works, the contents are empty
```

---

```
item = "first, second"
splitItems = item.split(', ')

splitItems[0] // Works, the contents are 'first'
splitItems[1] // Works, the contents are 'second'
```

Comment: how would i fix this?

Comment: I would start to check what the variable `item` contains. It should contain something like `first, second`. Two pieces of string seperated with a `, `. And see if you can figure out why it does not contain that information

Comment: which line is my error in then? The idx//enumerate part I was shown how to do, but do not understand it. Also, I am not very familiar with the .split function, and all that i am really able to do with it is make usernames. Also, this code does work when the leader-board needs updating: It is only when it doesn't that it is failing

Comment: The variable it contains is a tuple which contains the winners points and the username

Comment: Is `item` a tuple?

Comment: winner = (WinnerPoints, user)

Comment: Okay, that's good. However the error is occusing because `item` does not contain two or more strings seperated by `, `. What does `item` contain? The `.split(', ')` function splits a string `first, second` into an array `['first', 'second']`.

Comment: item was only used in that for loop: the code that was used was:::v###item.split(', ')[1] == winner[1] and int(item.split(', ')[0]) < int(winner[0]):###

Comment: So all it contains is the username and the points, e.g. winner could be : winner(56, 'User2')

Comment: The issue is with `item` not with `winner`. It has issues seperating `item` into an array using the `split` method.

Comment: ah, what can I do to avoid these issues?

Comment: Make sure that `item` actually contains a string that looks something like `first, second`.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that as i dont understand properly how that chunk of code works